# lvcGame, VBS and HLA setup Error 127 out of LVCGame

Tags: simulation, high-level-architecture

I am trying to setup VBS to talk HLA to a legacy app using LVCGame.

I am using [openRTI](http://sourceforge.net/p/openrti/wiki/Home/) currently in my project. I have LVCGame pointed to a directory with the following dlls:

- RTI-NG.dll
- OpenRIT.dll (copied from another folder)
- libRTI-NG.dll (copy of RTI-NG.dll and renamed)
- FedTime.dll

My vbsClient.config relevant lines:

```
Plugins = HLA-1.3.dll : HLA-1.3\Project\HLA.config
```

I am getting the following error out of LVCGame:

2014-12-31 10:48:03 INFO (LVCGAME::LVCGame::init) Initialised.

2014-12-31 10:48:03 ERROR (LVCGAME::LVCGame::start) 'class LVCGAME::UTILS::Exception' (src\LVCGame.cpp, line 766): Couldn't load plugin .\lib\HLA-1.3.dll. Error Code: 127

I did send an email to VBS support but it I had any idea what a 127 error was maybe I could get further.

I found that another free RTI [Portico](http://www.porticoproject.org/comingsoon/) implementation is mentioned as working with LVCgame giving that a try has pretty similar results I get and error 126 instead of a 127.

2015-01-02 09:47:47 INFO (LVCGAME::UTILS::IOUtils::extractDllLoadPath) Using DLL path specified as 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Portico\portico-2.0.1\bin\vc10'.
2015-01-02 09:47:47 INFO (LVCGAME::LVCGame::init) Initialised.
2015-01-02 09:47:47 ERROR (LVCGAME::LVCGame::start) 'class LVCGAME::UTILS::Exception' (src\LVCGame.cpp, line 766): Couldn't load plugin .\lib\HLA-1.3.dll. Error Code: 126

2015-01-02 09:47:47 ERROR (LVCGAME::LVCGame::start) LVCGame start failed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I found that Portico was creating a log file located in my VBS directory\logs.  From there I was able to see that Portico at least was not able to find my .fed file I had the path messed up.